# Warn user on login of AD accountExpires date

Tags: active-directory

I want to modify Linux login scripts so that when a user logs in, they will be notified of their accountExpires date on ActiveDirectory, with increasingly dire warnings as the date gets closer (60, 30, 15, 5, 1 day, etc.).

Two things are giving me grief. I want ldapsearch to only output "accountExpires: ######" and I need to convert that from the 100-nanosecond-intervals-since-1/1/1601 64 bit format to Day-Month-Year format.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out after a lot of trial and error…

```
#!/bin/bash
accountExpires=$(ldapsearch -d 0 -LLL -v -b "DC=<yourdomain>,DC=<yourdomainextension>" sAMAccountName=$(whoami) 2> /dev/null  | grep -oP 'accountExpires: \K.*' | tail -n 1)
if [ accountExpires = "9223372036854775807" ]; then
  echo "Account never expires."
else
  timeInSeconds=$((( accountExpires / 10000000 )))
  interval1601to1970=$((( 0 - $(date --date=1601-01-01 +%s) )))
  timeSince1970=$((( $timeInSeconds - $interval1601to1970 )))
  echo "Your account expires on: $(date --date @"$timeSince1970")"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

@JuanJimenez

Test with your script:

```
$ ./get-expired-date.sh 133169184000000000
Your account expires on: Fri Dec 30 23:52:48 WIB 2022
```

Test with powershell:

```
> cat .\getdate.ps1
[datetime]::fromfiletime(133169184000000000)

> .\getdate.ps1
31 December, 2022 7:00:00 AM
```

There are about 7 hours differences compare to powershell. Anyway thanks for the scripts.

Edit: Adding epoch diff to your script fix the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
accountExpires=$(ldapsearch -d 0 -LLL -v -b "DC=<yourdomain>,DC=<yourdomainextension>" sAMAccountName=$(whoami) 2> /dev/null  | grep -oP 'accountExpires: \K.*' | tail -n 1)
#accountExpires=$1
if [ accountExpires = "9223372036854775807" ]; then
  echo "Account never expires."
else
  timeInSeconds=$((( accountExpires / 10000000 )))
  interval1601to1970=$((( 0 - $(date --date=1601-01-01 +%s) )))
  correctionEpoch=25632
  timeSince1970=$((( $timeInSeconds - $interval1601to1970 + $correctionEpoch)))
  echo "Your account expires on: $(date --date @"$timeSince1970")"
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, well, Powershell is not Bash. 

Comment: And now that I think of it, it may be a timezone thing.

Comment: Hi @JuanJimenez Adding epoch 25632 to $timeSince1970 fix the problem.